# Синонимизировать [google-gson] и [gson]

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Предлагаю синонимизировать [google-gson](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-gson) и [gson](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gson).

Только надо бы выбрать, в какую сторону синонимизировать.

Comment: Нет смысла специально плодить дубликаты, несмотря на то, что старый вопрос остался без ответа.

Comment: Синонимизировать в какую сторону?

Comment: @Qwertiy У gson очень хорошее описание. Предлагаю оставить ее как основную. Ну или перенести описание в google-gson

Comment: Описание скопипастил.

Comment: @Qwertiy и зачем нам две метки с одинаковым описанием?

Comment: @alexolut, чтобы выбрать, к какой синонимизировать.

Comment: @Qwertiy Для этого нет смысла описание дубликатить. Надо просто объединять как следует. Без потери данных, то есть.

Comment: Вроде готово, принимай ответ.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Сделать метку [gson](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gson) основной.

Comment: А чего этот ответ не "общий"?

Comment: @alexolut, ну вообще-то забыл, но в принципе он мне больше нравится, так что пусть остаётся.

Comment: А как же выждать неделю до принятия решения? Это же рушит все принципы существования голосований на Мете! :-D

Comment: @alexolut, кто успел, тот и проголосовал))

Answer (score -1):

Сделать метку [google-gson](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-gson) основной.