# Синонимизация метки [gson]

Tags: предложение, метки, синонимы-меток

Сейчас обнаружил две метки [gson](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gson) (40 вопросов, 32 за год, есть описание) и [google-gson](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-gson) (44 вопроса, 11 за год, без описания). Есть предложение синонимизировать их, оставив основную метку [gson](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gson) (из-за детального описания)

Подобный попрос уже задавали [Синонимизировать [google-gson] и [gson]](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6196/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-google-gson-%D0%B8-gson) но он остался вообще без внимания

Comment: @alexolut, где-то не под тем вопросом ты обсуждаешь. Перенёс.

Comment: @Qwertiy где обсуждение, там и обсуждаю вообще-то!